# Cannot find a skin that matches family portal and version v1.2. We will use the skin portal.desktop

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, skin, webcenter

I have designed a login page in webcenter portal. The page has username and password fields and a command button. There is a managed bean also called LoginBean. What I want is when the user gives the username and password fields and hit the login button, the user will get a msg "Welcome" username in the next page. I have developed this thing in a jsf application. It's working fine there. As we know that webcenter portal is based on ADF and ADF is dependent on JSF so I thought that the same logic will work in ADF also. But when I am hitting the login button , I am getting "Cannot find a skin that matches family portal and version v1.2. We will use the skin portal.desktop"  msg in console. It's not even hitting the method which is written against the action attribute for the command button

Comment: are you using the action or actionListener attribute?

Answer (score 0):

These seem to be 2 different problems because the message in your console is just a warning (and thus not blocking).

To get rid of that message you need to modify your *trinidad-config.xml*. 
In that file remove the following tag (and it's value):

```
<skin-version>
```